# Unstable application uses SqlDependency. Several states and errors

Tags: threadpool, sqldependency, autoresetevent, waitone

I have a windows application using SqlDependency running at separated thread pool, this application represents a log monitor UI get the latest rows added in a specific table in the database and view it in a DataGridView. You can see the application source code from this [LINK](http://www.mediafire.com/download/kskfm8lo6l6kyli/OutgoingSMS_Monitor.rar), or follow this script.

```
    const string tableName = "OutgoingLog";
    const string statusMessage = "{0} changes have occurred.";
    int changeCount = 0;

    private static DataSet dataToWatch = null;
    private static SqlConnection connection = null;
    private static SqlCommand command = null;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool CanRequestNotifications()
    {
        // In order to use the callback feature of the
        // SqlDependency, the application must have
        // the SqlClientPermission permission.
        try
        {
            SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);

            perm.Demand();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // This event will occur on a thread pool thread.
        // Updating the UI from a worker thread is not permitted.
        // The following code checks to see if it is safe to
        // update the UI.
        ISynchronizeInvoke i = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;

        // If InvokeRequired returns True, the code
        // is executing on a worker thread.
        if (i.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Create a delegate to perform the thread switch.
            OnChangeEventHandler tempDelegate = new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            object[] args = { sender, e };

            // Marshal the data from the worker thread
            // to the UI thread.
            i.BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);

            return;
        }

        // Remove the handler, since it is only good
        // for a single notification.
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;

        dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

        // At this point, the code is executing on the
        // UI thread, so it is safe to update the UI.
        ++changeCount;
        lblChanges.Text = String.Format(statusMessage, changeCount);

        // Reload the dataset that is bound to the grid.
        GetData();
    }

    AutoResetEvent running = new AutoResetEvent(true);

    private void GetData()
    {
        // Start the retrieval of data on another thread to let the UI thread free
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            running.WaitOne();

            // Empty the dataset so that there is only
            // one batch of data displayed.
            dataToWatch.Clear();

            // Make sure the command object does not already have
            // a notification object associated with it.
            command.Notification = null;

            // Create and bind the SqlDependency object
            // to the command object.
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dataToWatch, tableName);



                try
                {
                    running.Set();
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Update the UI
                    dgv.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        dgv.DataSource = dataToWatch;
                        dgv.DataMember = tableName;

                        //dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.Rows.Count - 1;
                    }));
                }


            }
        });
    }

    private void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changeCount = 0;
        lblChanges.Text = String.Format(statusMessage, changeCount);

        // Remove any existing dependency connection, then create a new one.
        SqlDependency.Stop("Server=.; Database=SMS_Tank_Log;UID=sa;PWD=hana;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        SqlDependency.Start("Server=.; Database=SMS_Tank_Log;UID=sa;PWD=hana;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

        if (connection == null)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.; Database=SMS_Tank_Log;UID=sa;PWD=hana;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

        }

        if (command == null)
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("select * from OutgoingLog", connection);

            //SqlParameter prm =
            //    new SqlParameter("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            //prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            //prm.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            //prm.Value = 100;
            //command.Parameters.Add(prm);
        }

        if (dataToWatch == null)
        {
            dataToWatch = new DataSet();
        }

        GetData();
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnAction.Enabled = CanRequestNotifications();
    }

    private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop("Server=.; Database=SMS_Tank_Log;UID=sa;PWD=hana;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    }
```

**The problem:**
I have many situations of errors, **(images in the first comment)**

**(No. 1)**: 
I got this error dialog, and I don't know its reason.

**(No. 2)**: 
I got nothing in my grid view (No errors, and no data).

**(No. 3)**: 
I got only columns names and no rows, although the table has rows.

I need help please.

Comment: **The problem:**
I have many situations of errors,

**(No. 1)**: 
http://s7.postimg.org/9dpwvamej/image.png
I got this error shown in the previous link.

**(No. 2)**: 
http://s24.postimg.org/y1ln3hmsl/image.png
I got nothing in my grid view.

**(No. 3)**: 
http://s9.postimg.org/oh6qz8sn3/image.png
I got only columns names and no rows, although the table has rows.

I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but a *DataSet* does not seem to have **notification** capability so the *DataGridView* may be surprised if you change it behind its back.

You could try to explicitly show your're changing the data source by first setting it to null:

```
dgv.DataSource = null;
dgv.DataSource = dataToWatch;
dgv.DataMember = tableName;
```

It's worth a try...

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I can not understand the reason of this three errors, and also what are the basics of errors or why they appears and on what depends ?

Comment: And with a "dgv.Refresh()" after "dgv.DataSource = null;"?

Comment: dgv.DataSource = null;
dgv.Refresh();
this code script makes data grid view blinks more than one time withing one second, by removing data source and rebind again.

We need a new scenario for this issue, beginning of run it into a separated thread bool with avoiding these errors.

I have a headache because of this application.

Comment: Yes .. the same errors, please see the my previous comment to understand what happens after the last modification

Comment: Looking in Google: seems to be a bug/feature with the DataGridView. Some people fixed it by doing this small tricks but does not seem enough in your case :( I'll have a look at your recent answer.