# how to have multiple people working on same data in datagrid

Tags: wpf, database, vb.net, datagrid, refresh

I am writing a vb.net/WPF program that will have a datagrid. Multiple people will be using this program at the same time so I need to try to keep everyone's datagrid refreshed and matching. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I thought I would set a background worker to every so often just refresh the datatable and refill the datagrid. I am not sure if this is the best strategy so am looking to SO for suggestions. One of the problems I have with this method is that when the datagrid is refilled it loses any sorting that the user may have applied.

Comment: @MitchWheat I may be missing something. I think this helps with making sure that users don't overwrite each other information but I am not sure how this might be applied to periodically updating the WPF datagrid while a user is using the program without it suddenly reordering the table.

Comment: @MitchWheat Okay, thanks. No just to figure how to visually keep it updated.

Comment: @MitchWheat I have not found a good answer yet as I don't believe we have addressed the process of updating the datagrid for the user. I can keep my data updated. I may write an answer of my own at some point. I do appreciate your response though.

Answer (score 1):

A periodic polled refresh and a manual refresh button are commonly used.

Another option (assuming you are targeting SQL Server) is to use [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) to 'tell' you when data changes rather than polling.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033033/sqldependency-using-backgroundworker) describes some approaches.

[Using Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.80).aspx)

[Using SqlDependency in a Windows Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: When I refresh the datagrid it removes any row selections the user may have made and undoes any sorting they may have done.